# Python converting a hexString

Tags: python, type-conversion, format, byte

Working with NFC with pyscard I received a hexstring like this "01 CB"

I need to convert it to something like that b'\x01\xCB'

--

I know it is a 2 octet big endian and should be equal to 459.

I basically want to run that after the conversion int.from_bytes(b'\x01\xCB', byteorder='big')

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need just integer value you might simply remove space and treat it just like hex-number i.e.:

```
string = "01 CB"
digits = string.replace(" ","")
value = int(digits,16)
print(value)
```

Output:

```
459
```

[`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)'s second (optional) argument is `base` - this can be any number from 2 to 36.

Comment: Right what I was looking for thank you! How would you go on converting the other way around? hex(value) seems to be the right start but how would you go matching the format?

Comment: @Garronde: if I would have to deal with values from `0` to `65535` (inclusive) I would unleash `awk`-style formatting following way: `value = 459; string = "%02X %02X" % (value//256, value%256); print(string)` which result in output: `01 CB`.